# Remove leading or trailing spaces but not spaces in between the text or words on Excel

Tags: excel

How to remove one or multiple spaces before and after the actual string. The spaces between the string have to be stay in place. The number of spaces (leading/trailing/between) varies.

Examples:

```
"1234   456abc    "
"  1234  456bac    "
"    1234 456cab    "
```

Result should be:

```
"1234   456abc"
"1234  456bac"
"1234 456cab"
```

Comment: have you tried TRIM() ? usually does that fine, but checking the help will remove intermediate spaces...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to retain all the intermediate spaces, the easiest way is with a short User Defined Function.

```
Function vbaTRIM(S As String) As String
    vbaTRIM = Trim(S)
End Function
```

If you cannot use VBA, you can use this rather complex array function:

```
=MID(A1,MATCH(TRUE,(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1)<>CHAR(32)),0),
LOOKUP(2,1/(MID(A1&" ",ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1)+1)),1)<>CHAR(32)),
ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1)+1)))-MATCH(TRUE,(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1)<>CHAR(32)),0)+1)
```

To enter/confirm an **array formula**, hold down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>. If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula seen in the formula bar.

There are two main parts of this function:

**Find first non-space**

```
=MATCH(TRUE,(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1)<>CHAR(32)),0)
```

**Find last non-space**

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(MID(A1&" ",ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1)+1)),1)<>CHAR(32)),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1)+1)))
```

So then, to return just the spaces stripped from the start and end:

```
=mid(a1,firstNonSpace,lastNonSpace-firstNonSpace+1)
```

If you enter these segments of the formula into some cell, and use the formula evaluation tool, you should be able to figure out how they work.

**EDIT**

If you have a newer version of Excel, with the `FILTERXML` function, you can try:

```
=FILTERXML("<s>" & A1 & "</s>", "//s")
```

Answer (score 0):

VBA should be the easiest, if you want a formula then try this

[image]

> =MID(A1,FIND(LEFT(TRIM(A1),1),A1),(LEN(A1)-MATCH(RIGHT(TRIM(A1),1),INDEX(MID(A1,LEN(A1)-ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1)))+1,1),0),0)-FIND(LEFT(TRIM(A1),1),A1)+2))

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the leading/trailing spaces in place, select a column of the values to be changed and run this sub procedure.

```
Sub removeLeadingTrailingSpaces()

    With Selection
        .TextToColumns Destination:=.Cells(1), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
                       FieldInfo:=Array(0, 2)
    End With

End Sub
```